# Where can I find a user forum for the brand-new Apple iBooks Author application?

Tags: books, ibooks-author

Apple has just released the free

### [iBooks Author](http://www.apple.com/ibooks-author/)

application for Mac OS X 10.7 Lion. Where can I find some information about its capabilities. Yes, this is a "Jeopardy" question.

Comment: I say you've found a darn good one right here where you're asking.

Comment: Yes, but since iBooks Author was released just today, the Apple discussion forum was the first place to go to get impressions from several different people trying out the software.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a new Apple Support Forum for iBooks Author

https://discussions.apple.com/community/mac_app_store/ibooks_author

Answer (score 2):

This is not a direct answer to your question, but it does offer places to find information about its capabilities. I found this collection of links so useful, therefore I want to share it here:

### Support Documents for iBooks Author

- [Publishing and distribution FAQ](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5071)
- [Use iPad-safe fonts when authoring books](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5072)
- [How to make your iBooks accessible](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5073)
- [Best practices for using 3D models](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5093)
- [About the Keynote widget](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5067)
- [Add video to your iBooks](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT5065)